# How to invoke a method on classes that implement a generic interface using reflection

Tags: c#, .net-core

I would like to invoke a method on objects in the currently running assembly that implement certain interface.

I have:

- an interface `IMyContract<T>` where T is a class.
- two models: `MyContractModel` and `MyContractModel2`.
- two services: `MyContractService` that implements
  `IMyContract<MyContractModel>` and `MyContractService2` that
  implements `IMyContract<MyContractModel2>`
- injections in host
  services as: `services.AddSingleton<IMyContract<MyContractModel>, MyContractService>()` and `services.AddSingleton<IMyContract<MyContractModel2>, MyContractService2>()`.

I am able to fetch the proper interface from the assembly and load the service instances from the dependency injections but I am not able to call methods. I get late binding error as the compiler is not aware of the type.

Is this not doable? If so, can you please suggest alternatives? Appreciate any help. Thanks.

Here is my code:

```cs
// Register services
var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
serviceCollection.AddSingleton<IMyContract<MyContractModel>, MyContractService>();
serviceCollection.AddSingleton<IMyContract<MyContractModel2>, MyContractService2>();
var serviceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();

// Load all contract processors (that implement `IMyContract`) and invoke `Process` on them
var iContractPrcessor = typeof(IMyContract<>);

IEnumerable<Type> allTypesInThisAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes();

foreach(Type type in allTypesInThisAssembly)
{
    if (type.GetInterface(iContractPrcessor.Name.ToString()) != null)
    {
        // As expected in 1st iteration, produces IMyContract<MyContractModel> 
        Type implementedInterface = type.GetInterface(iContractPrcessor.Name.ToString());

        // As expected in 1st iteration, produces MyContractService
        var contractService = serviceProvider.GetService(implementedInterface);

        MethodInfo method = iContractPrcessor.GetMethod("Process");

        //This throws an exception: late bound operation exception
        var result = (Task) method.Invoke(contractService, null);
        await result.ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}

public interface IMyContract<T> where T : class
{
    Task Process();
}

public class MyContractModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = "";
}

public class MyContractService : IMyContract<MyContractModel>
{
    public Task Process()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("MyContractService Process");
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}

public class MyContractModel2
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = "";
}

public class MyContractService2 : IMyContract<MyContractModel2>
{
    public Task Process()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("MyContractService2 Process");
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? You are adding the types to dependency injection, which implies the types are in the assembly or directly referenced, but then you are using reflection you get at the same types & invoke methods. Why aren't you just using DI to get the objects by injecting them into a constructor, or getting the singleton instance via IServiceProvider? I can understand needing reflection if you are dynamically loading plugins, what's the use case of this code?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yeah....this is a bit simplified view. The part of the application that needs the dynamic part should not really be cognizant of how many contract services that implement the interface are available in the code. But yes....there is an assumption that all contract services are loaded in the DI. Does it make more sense?

Comment: It's hard to follow, but I suspect that the type on which you're trying to invoke the method is an open generic type.  Instead of trying to invoke the method on `iContractPrcessor` which is `IMyContract<>`, you need to call `iContractProcessor.MakeGenericType(t)`. That type will be `IMyContract<whatever T is>`.

Comment: It's less clear why you're trying to invoke a method on the interface, if I'm reading it correctly. You'd want to invoke it on a type that implements the interface. Or perhaps now that you have the "real" generic type you could resolve that from the DI container and invoke the method on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting the `MethodInfo` from `typeof(IMyContract<>)` ( `iContractPrcessor`.)

```cs
MethodInfo method = iContractPrcessor.GetMethod("Process");
//               ^^^ typeof(IMyContract<>) ^^^
```

...but you're trying to invoke that method using a different type - the concrete type that implements the interface, like `typeof(MyContractService)`, which implements `IMyContract<MyContractModel>`.

```cs
var result = (Task) method.Invoke(contractService, null);
//                            ^^ object of concrete type ^^
```

So you're trying to invoke the method from one type - `IMyContract<>` - on another type - `MyContractService`.

Instead, once you've got the concrete type, get the "Process" method from that type.

Change

```cs
MethodInfo method = iContractPrcessor.GetMethod("Process");
```

to

```cs
MethodInfo method = contractService.GetType().GetMethod("Process");
```

Now you're

- Getting the type that implements the interface
- Getting the method *from that type*
- Invoking the method on an instance of that type

---

You can go deeper. All of this assumes that the concrete services all have one method named "Process," and that it is the one corresponding to the interface method. That might not be true. There could be multiple "Process" methods.

What if you're confident that you have the right method on the interface, but you want to be certain that you've got the corresponding method on the class?

You could do this:

```cs
// Get the interface type with the generic type specified
var genericInterfaceType = iContractPrcessor.MakeGenericType(t);

// Get the "Process" method on the interface. 
var genericInterfaceMethod = genericInterfaceType.GetMethod("Process");

// Get a mapping of the interface's members to the concrete "target type" members.
InterfaceMapping interfaceMap = contractService.GetType()
    .GetInterfaceMap(genericInterfaceType);

// Find the index of the interface's Process method
// in the interface method collection
var interfaceMethodIndex = interfaceMap.InterfaceMethods.ToList()
    .IndexOf(genericInterfaceMethod);

// Get the method from the target type method collection with the same index.
// This is the method you want to invoke. 
// It is the method on the service that implements the interface method.
var contractServiceMethod = interfaceMap.TargetMethods[interfaceMethodIndex];
```

I had never heard of [`InterfaceMap`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.interfacemapping) because I've never tried to solve this problem.

And although I'm addressing the question as asked, I can't rule out that there's a totally different, easier solution.

Comment: Wow....this actually worked: ```MethodInfo method = contractService.GetType().GetMethod("Process");```. I also appreciate the other explanation.